# JQuery/CSS Hide cookie banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple cookie banner:

```
  <div id="cookie-consent" class="cookie-consent">
      <span>This site uses cookies to enhance user experience. see <a href="..." target="_blank" class="ml-1 text-decoration-none">Privacy policy</a> </span>
      <div  class="mt-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center g-2">
        <button id="cookie-ok-button" class="cookie-allow-button mr-1">I'm aware</button>            
      </div>          
    </div>
```

I use jquery to hide the banner when users click the ok button:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

if (window.localStorage.getItem('accept_cookies'))
{
    $('#cookie-consent').css('display','none');
}

$("#cookie-ok-button").click(function()
{              
    $('#cookie-consent').fadeOut();
    $('#cookie-consent').css('display','none');
    window.localStorage.setItem('accept_cookies', true);              
}); 
});
```

It works but sometimes on Chrome the banner appears before rapidly disappearing. Is there any modification I can do to avoid such behavior.

Comment: The banner will only be hidden once the JS file has been loaded/run, which can happen after the first render of the page. The easiest option is to use JS to show the banner inside the document-ready, rather than being visible by default.

Comment: Start out with the element not showing and change the logic of the if statement to show it if the local storage is falsy

Comment: I tried to add display:none by default on CSS and modifying the js as "if (window.localStorage.getItem('accept_cookies') === false)
    {
        $('#cookie-consent').css('display','block');
    }" but the banner is never shown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of showing the banner by default and conditionally hiding it, hide it by default and conditionally show it.

For example:

```
<div id="cookie-consent" class="cookie-consent" style="display:none;">
  <!--- etc. -->
</div>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  if (!window.localStorage.getItem('accept_cookies'))
  {
    $('#cookie-consent').css('display','block');
  }

  // etc.
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this approach but by checking with "===false". Thank you!